# FileProvider: Снимаю фото, но не могу его получить в приложении

Tags: android

Мне необходимо снять фото и достать его в приложении.

**Папку я создал и снятые фото сохраняются там.
Всё работает на android с весией АПИ ниже 25.**

`FileProvider` я не использовал раньше, делаю впервые. Документация без примеров идёт.

**Вот код для создания intent** для версий ниже android N и с доп. условием для апи выше 25:

```
public static Uri picUri;
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(Context context) {

    File cacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    cacheDir.mkdirs();
    String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
    } else {
        picUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), imageFile);
    }

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        takePhotoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

    return takePhotoIntent;
}
```

**Вызываю метод так**

```
startActivityForResult(UtilsPhoto.getPickImageIntent(getContext()), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

В `onActivityResult()` `data.getData();` равен `null`.

**Манифест:**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="picDirectory/"/>
</paths>
```

**`strings.xml:`**

```
<string name="file_provider_authority">ru.pics.app.provider</string>
```

**Мне кажется, что provider_paths у меня не правильный**. Любая помощь не помешает)

Логи:

```
10-09 17:33:32.839 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
    10-09 17:33:32.845 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at ru.test.app.screen.profile.mypage.MyProfileFragment.getPathFromCameraData(MyProfileFragment.java:695)
    10-09 17:33:32.845 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at ru.test.app.screen.profile.mypage.MyProfileFragment.onActivityResult(MyProfileFragment.java:627)
    10-09 17:33:32.845 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:149)
    10-09 17:33:32.845 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at ru.test.app.screen.maincatalog.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:329)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7226)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4477)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4524)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1691)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    10-09 17:33:32.846 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    10-09 17:33:32.847 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    10-09 17:33:32.847 20484-20484/ru.test.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: А в логе что нибудь есть?

Comment: настораживает `putExtra("return-data", true);` - что это?

Comment: Имя папки Вы берёте из strings app_name, а в paths пишете "picDirectory" - они у Вас идентичны?

Comment: @Barmaley лог с ошибкой добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Barmaley `настораживает putExtra("return-data", true); - что это?` - про эту строчку уже не помню, зачем добавлял)

Comment: @woesss да, они идентичны. Фотография сохраняется в этой папке. В памяти телефона есть эта папка в корне, в ней и сохраняется, а вот оттуда достать не могу через onActivityResult

Comment: @Barmaley Фотография сохраняется в памяти телефона, там есть папка в корне, в ней сохраняется фото, а вот оттуда достать не могу через onActivityResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Напишу здесь, вдруг кому-то поможет.

До этого я сохранял в корне памяти телефона папку и туда файлы с камеры.
Сейчас же я создаю файлы в "песочнице" проекта. Как я понял, provider_paths сейчас как раз содержит путь к корню этой "песочницы". Конечно, я не разобрался пока ещё с правильным путём к папке в корне телефона, но это рабочий код

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**xml/provider_paths.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Метод, который надо вызвать:

```
private void loadPhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent takeCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
            photoFile = createTempFile(getContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        photoFile);
            } else {
                photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            }
            takeCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            takeCaptureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(takeCaptureIntent, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public static File createTempFile(Context context) throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image =  File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, image.getAbsolutePath());

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    return image;
}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {

                    Uri selectedImage;
                    String path = null;

                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        path = Uri.fromFile(photoFile).getPath();
                    }

                    if (path != null) {
                        Log.e("sds", path);
                        pathToPicture = path;
                        Glide.with(activity)
                                .load(new File(path))
                                .centerCrop()
                                .into(ava);
                    }
                }
                break;
                //case...
            }
        }
    }
```